# Necessity of -> Void in Swift

Tags: swift, closures

In the following code (using the Parse library), I have:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // yada yada
})
```

Is the `-> Void in` necessary in the code (rather, is there something else I can use?  Removing it throws errors in Xcode.)?

I am *very* new to Swift, so this may be a dumb question...

Comment: `-> Void` is unnecessary but `in` is a required bit of syntax, not fluff.

Answer (score 3):

The `in` line is how you get the parameters into the block:

```
(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

If the *types* are known in some other way, you can omit *them*:

```
objects, error in
```

But you cannot omit the `in` line entirely unless you pick up the parameters in some other way in your code (as `$0` and `$1`), and that would make your code difficult to understand. It's better to keep the `in` line so you know what the parameters are.

Comment: Deleting the `in` throws an error, and doesn't even seem to be an option.  There's no shorthand I can use?

Comment: My book teaches you the rules for what you are allowed to omit: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_anonymous_functions

Comment: Yes, actually @matt I did.  Your last sentence "it's better to keep the `in` line so you know what the parameters are" seems to imply that you can remove the `in`.

Comment: But it also says you _can't_ do that _unless_ you pick up the parameters as `$0` and `$1` in your code. Don't make me say the same thing over and over. Read what I _did_ say and think about it.

Comment: I actually did read your answer several times.  I wouldn't have asked for clarification if it is as crystal clear as you thought it was.  Also, you can omit the `-> Void` as commented on my question by @CodaFi, so you didn't even fully answer my question -- just because you commented "`-> Void` _can_ be omitted" on another question, but then didn't include it in your answer, doesn't make your answer complete.  Thanks.

Comment: I _did_ include it in my answer. Look where I show omission of the `-> Void`. I say you can omit the _types_. Void is a type. And I give an example: `object, error in`. See? No `-> Void`. The problem is that you do not _listen_ to the answer you are given. - Also I wrote you a whole book that explains it to you, and gave you a link to the relevant section.

Answer (score 0):

This `-> Void in` is saying the closure is not returning anything and what follows the `in` is the body of the closure. The `-> Void` can be removed because Swift is very good at inferring types. The `in` is necessary.

> The start of the closure’s body is introduced by the `in` keyword. This keyword indicates that the definition of the closure’s parameters and return type has finished, and the body of the closure is about to begin.

You can go read more about closures here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: So there's nothing I can replace that cleans it up?  IMO in the actual code it seems out of place.

Comment: This is just wrong. `-> Void` _can_ be omitted (usually).